# Why is my Springboot application not starting up?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, jhipster

I bootstrapped the springboot application with JHipster but I have not been able to get it start up . It says build success but won't start up on a server . There is an embedded tomcat server added to the POM.XML , what could be wrong ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.fromIssuerLocation(ClientRegistrations.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getBuilderFromIssuerIfPossible(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistration(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.lambda$getClientRegistrations$0(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:53)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 118 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:209)
    ... 130 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:563)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1261)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1194)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1082)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    ... 133 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I mean, the error seems pretty clear - the issuer you specified can't be reached. Is it (JHipster I assum) running? On the port you specified in your spring-boot app?

Comment: Your program seems using jhipster. you can remove the dependency from jhipster. just start a pure spring boot program. As you have not provided pom.xml and applicaton.properties file. So identifying the root cause is not straight forward here.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that keycloak is started before running the springboot app because jhispter provides ready to use keycloak config. The app tries to reach keycloak at `localhost:9080`.

If you have docker and docker-compose installed you can use the provided docker-compose configuration and start keycloak via `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up`

If you want to start it manually you need to make sure to setup the jhipster realm in your keycloak instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check 9080 port
Is it use by another process
You can do it by this command : netstat -aon
Then kill process by processor: taskkill -f /pid process_id

Comment: The error is not the port is already in use, rather there is no process is running in port 9080.